# How is the energy of electron related to the force of attraction between the nucleus?

Tags: forces, energy, electrons

I don't seem to understand the working of electron and its force and its motion around nucleus.
What are the factors affecting it?
And how is it said that in this shell the electron has this much kinetic energy?
Please recommend me some book where i can understand these.

Comment: The kinetic & potential energy of a closed system are related via the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem).

Comment: You need a book course  on quantum mechanics. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html